# Error on keyword "context" in Navigator.push statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to navigate to a new page in the action of an onPressed() in this button below but am getting an error (red squiggly line) on the use of the keyword context and I am not sure why.  This is the error I am getting:

> Undefined name 'context'. Try correcting the name to one that is
> defined, or defining the name.

and here is the code:

```
FloatingActionButton BuildLoginButton(String signInType, Widget loginMethod) {
  return FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loginMethod),
      );
    },
    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/${signInType}_logo.png',
        height: 32, width: 32),
    //signInType = signInType[0].toUpperCase() + signInType.substring(1),
    label: Text('Sign in with $signInType'),
    backgroundColor: WHITE_COLOR,
    foregroundColor: DARK_COLOR,
  );
}
```

Comment: I think I need to build the context somewhere in my FAB function before using it in the Navigator function.  Can someone advise the best way to do that?

Comment: if this function is in a stateless widget, then you must pass the context to this function to use it because in a stateless widget the context is only in the build function, otherwise, you can make your class a stateful widget and then you will be free to use the context anywhere in the class

Comment: thank you @omarhatem but i do not fully understand.  because this function is a standalone widget.  but how do i pass in the context to this function BuildLoginButton ?

Comment: Add context to your widget:
FloatingActionButton BuildLoginButton(BuildContext context, String signInType, Widget loginMethod) {}

Then pass the context when calling the widget:
floatingActionButton: BuildLoginButton(context, '', Container()),